# React Native FlatList styling

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a Flat List and I am doing so with a Pure Component. Currently I have quite a few views wrapped within one another to get my desired effect of having a background color that does not take up the entire row height, so the rows appear to have space between one another. However, as shown by the picture I am having a slight issue with the color appearing fluent across the row. I am not sure why this is happening. (The yellow line right before the 0).
[image]

Here is my code for the row component. There is an initial blank view to add some beginning space to the row.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress}>
    <View style={styles.items}>
        <View style={styles.holder}>
            <Text style={styles.text}></Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.title}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.open}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>0</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Here is the styling I am using as well.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

items: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 48,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',

},
holder: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#C8102E',
},
title: {
    flex: 8,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#C8102E',
},
open: {
    flex: 2,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#C8102E',
},
text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
},

});
```

Comment: Can you put the total code?  Since I am sure that it Inherited this color some where outside of this scope! A higher level I mean.

Comment: @Reza What do you mean? Everything from the class is shown. The color is gotten from the styles shown below.

Comment: OK, I thought that it is part of the code. Can't you force a color in 'items' for that?

Comment: @Reza The issue isn't setting a color, it is the slight yellow line shown in the image that I do not understand why it is appearing.